# Center fields using Bootstrap

Tags: html, button, input, bootstrap-4, center

I'm newbie using bootstrap, so I would like you help to center these couple of textBoxes and the button. I appreciate if there any other enhancement I can do with the code

This is part of the code I did and I'm using this as template: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-agency

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" class="textbox" id="txt_uname" name="txt_uname" placeholder="Username" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" class="textbox" id="txt_uname" name="txt_pwd" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase"  type="submit" value="Submit" name="but_submit" id="but_submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The final idea is to have something like this:

[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf6Zy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this can help you. Just add "m-auto" class to col-md-6

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <form method="post" action="">
          <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" class="textbox" id="txt_uname" name="txt_uname" placeholder="Username" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" class="textbox" id="txt_uname" name="txt_pwd" placeholder="Password"/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase"  type="submit" value="Submit" name="but_submit" id="but_submit" />
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flex too, see this link to more information: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Basically, you can use `<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">...</div>` to center your div. In my opnion you can use grid to define the macro layout of your view, for example, use grid to define the number of columns in one component of your view and inside this component you can use flexbox. This approach make the view more responsive. And if you understand flexbox you can do anything. I hope this help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="text-center"><!-- Code goes here --></div>
```